# Is there a way to detect whitespace after a string in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I want a code that will detect if there is whitespace at the end of a string in Python and return a true or false so it can be used in a conditional, is there a way to do this? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

You can try:

```
your_string.endswith(" ")
```

But, if you want to match any kind of white space, you can use:

```
import re

re.match(r".*\s$", your_string)
```

[`re.UNICODE`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) flag can be also useful if you work with Python 2:

```
import re

re.match(r".*\s$", your_string, flags=re.UNICODE)
```